# Call All User API with angular

Tags: html, angular, api

I have problem calling API to HTML. The log is show up but the data is not show up on the html. How to call this type API properly? I'm using fuse Angular for the layout and data stuff

This is the HTML and Component

```js
export class UserGroupTeamComponent implements OnInit
{
    members: any;

    constructor(private _CloudUserServer:CloudUserService)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
       this.getMembers();

        
    }
    async getMembers(): Promise<any> {
        this.members = await this._CloudUserServer.getUsers();
        console.log('abc',this.members)
      }

    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex flex-col mt-8 divide-y border-t">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let member of members">
            <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row sm:items-center py-6">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <div class="ml-4">
                        <div class="font-medium" *ngIf="members">{{member.name}}</div>
                        <div class="text-secondary">{{member.email}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

this is CloudUserService

```js
async getUsers(limit?: number, lastKey?: string, filter?: string): Promise<any> {
        const headers = {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
            Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()}`
        };
        const body = {};
        const options = {headers: headers, body: body};
        const limitParam = limit ? '&limit=' + limit.toString() : '';
        const idParam = lastKey ? '&id=' + lastKey : '';
        const filterParam = filter ? '&filter=%25' + filter + '%25' : '';

        const path = `${this._userUrl}/users?${limitParam}${idParam}${filterParam}`;

        const promise = API.get(this._apiName, path, options).then(
            (result) => {
              console.log('getUsers result', result);
              return result.message;
            },
            (err) => {
              console.log('getUsers err', err.response);
              throw(err.response);
            }
        );

        return promise;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

The result should be all user name and user show up.

Comment: Have you tried to use async pipe `*ngFor="let member of members | async"`?